# jQuery - filter on multiple conditions

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a filter based on multiple conditions, I would like to combine data and css properties.

Example:
I have multiple DIVs with a data attribute called "data-group" and among DIVs sharing the same data-group value, I would like to target DIVs that have relative positionning.

```
<div id="a" data-group="1" style="position:fixed">
<div id="b" data-group="1" style="position:relative"> 
<div id="c" data-group="1" style="position:fixed">
<div id="d" data-group="0" style="position:fixed">
```

I would like to create filter grouping all DIVs with data-group=1 and fixed position.

When I only have one condition, I tend to use the following:

```
common = $("div").filter(function() {  return $(this).attr("data-group") === 1;          });
```

...but how can I apply a second condition?

Thanks!

Laurent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter `fixed`:

```
common = $("div").filter(function() {  
  return $(this).attr("data-group") === 1 && $(this).css('position') === 'fixed';
});
```

Filter `relative`:

```
common = $("div").filter(function() {  
  return $(this).attr("data-group") === 1 && $(this).css('position') === 'relative';
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do it similar to the way you're doing it now:

```
common =  $("div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("data-group") == 1 && this.style.position == 'fixed' ;
});
```

Or with a one-liner:

```
common = $('div[data-group="1"][style="position:fixed"]');
```

Comment: Thanks, I flagged correct answer for the first one to post but your answer is equally good. For the one line, does it also work with a position that is set in the css instead of inline?

Comment: No for that you'd need JavaScript and `getComputedStyle`